# Matlab: how to apply point-wise function on a matrix?

Tags: function, matlab, matrix

I am using Matlab to do one of my projects. I am stuck at one basic thing.

I have 2 matricies - A and B and a vector V. What I want to do is this:

A(i, j) = V(B(i,j)) for all i, j.

I tried doing this in the most obvious way - nested loops. For some reason, A is not getting populated. Am I missing something? Is there a more efficient (in-built function) way of doing this.

Thanks,

Anil.

Comment: Can you put your code so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: Yes, A and B are of the same size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all entries in `B` are integers larger than zero, and if the maximum of `B` is not larger than the number of elements in `V`, then you can simply write

```
A = V(B);
```

Comment: I totally screwed up by not trying this simple thing. Is there a simple way if I want to apply a particular function on each of the elements in the matrix. Say, A(i,j) = B(i,j)^x ?

Comment: @Anil Katti: `A=B.^x` is what you're looking for. The `.` applies the operation in element-wise fashion.